# Eloquent relationship property in vuejs via props

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am having problem accessing eloquent's association from within VueJS component via props.

So am passing a model object to vue component, like this:

Comment model

```
public function post()
{
   return belongsTo('App\Post');
}
```

Comment controller

```
$comments = Comment::all()
return view('comments', ['comments' => $comments);
```

comment blade

```
<comment-index :comments="{{ $comments }}"></comment-index>
```

comment vue component

```
<template>
   <div>
      <table>
          <tr v-for="comment in comments">
             <td>{{ comment.message }}
             <td>{{ comment.post.title }} // post is undefined
          </tr>
      </table>
   </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['comments'] 
    }
</script>
```

But if if I loop and dump the post in the controller, the post shows in the vue template:

```
$comments = Comment::all()

foreach($comments as $comment) {
   dump($comment->post->title);
}
return view('comments', ['comments' => $comments);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Vue on `comment.blade` the `post` is not lazy loaded while it is being lazy loaded when you access it via `$comment->post->title` on your controller.

From the [`Laravel docs`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

> When accessing Eloquent relationships as properties, the relationship
>   data is "lazy loaded". This means the relationship data is not
>   actually loaded until you first access the property.

Since you are using Vue (client-side) to access `post`, lazy loading will not work and thus it is not loaded when you access it like this: `{{ comment.post.title }}` leading to it's value being `undefined`.

To solve this, you can eager load the comment `post` by doing this.

```
$comments = Comment::with('post')->get();
```

Also if you don't lazy load the comment's post and the comments grow larger, it may lead to some performance issue with `N + 1` query problem.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you

Comment: @Ana he did not even encode his $comments within props

Comment: @Riza You're welcome and I'm just wondering, how did you manage to pass `$comments` without  encoding it like this `:comments="'{!! json_encode($comments) !!}'"` as @ThamerBelfkih also mentioned.

Comment: I didn't need to encode it, it just works.  Using Laravel 5.7

Comment: @Riza Cool, that's good to know that it behaves like that now. Thanks.